# How to find smallest string in result tree fragment(RTF) containing two strings without using extension function e.g. node-set in xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt

I have two strings variables basically storing currency codes which can have values like USD or EUR or JPY etc.

Examples:
If variable boughtccy contains 'JPY' and variable soldccy contains 'USD' then it should return a string 'BOUGHTCCY' signifying that it is the variable named boughtccy actually contains the smallest currency.

Similarly, if variable boughtccy contains 'EUR' and variable soldccy contains 'AUD' then it should return a string 'SOLDCCY' signifying that it is the variable named soldccy actually contains the smallest currency.

I have written following code which works perfectly fine except for in Altova XMLSpy. I have a requirement that it should also work in XMLSpy.

Here is the code:

```
xsl:variable name="smallerccy">
  <xsl:variable name="nodes">
    <node>
      <xsl:value-of select="$boughtccy"/>
    </node>
    <node>
      <xsl:value-of select="$soldccy"/>
    </node>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:for-each select="common:node-set($nodes)/*">
    <xsl:sort select="."/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="position()=1 and .=$boughtccy">BOUGHTCCY</xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="position()=1 and .=$soldccy">SOLDCCY</xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

How do I achieve this without using exslt:node-set() function? I cannot use xslt 2.0.

Comment: Altova XMLSpy supports XSLT 2.0 and even 3.0 and I think its XSLT 1.0 implementation does not require the use of a `node-set` extension function to select nodes in an RTF so you could use system-property and/or function-available to check what kind of implementation the code is run with and use the appropriate approach.

Comment: When you say "smallest" currency, are you actually looking for the first currency alphabetically?

Comment: Yes, smallest currency means the first currency alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the underlying problem you are having is that in XSLT 1.0 strings can only compared only for equality (or inequality), and so you can simply do `<xsl:when test="$boughtccy > $soldccy">`

In you particular case, where you are dealing with a finite number of strings, you could define a variable containing all possible currency codes, and use string handling to find one is first.

Try this XSLT (You would, of course, have to amend `$AllCurrencies` to have all possible currency codes).

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:variable name="AllCurrencies" select="'AUS|EUR|JPY|USD'" />

  <xsl:param name="boughtccy" select="'JPY'" />
  <xsl:param name="soldccy" select="'USD'" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="string-length(substring-before($AllCurrencies, $boughtccy)) &lt; string-length(substring-before($AllCurrencies, $soldccy))">BOUGHTCCY</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>SOLDCCY</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. Unfortunately, even though there is a finite number of currencies in the world but they are about 180 in total. The example which I gave is just an example. Practically, the variables boughtccy and soldccy can have any currency out of those 180 possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I would write conditional logic, using system-property() and function-available(), that implements this in different ways for different processors:

- if it's XSLT 2.0, use `min(($boughtccy, $soldccy))`
- if it's XSLT 1.0 with a node-set extension, use the sorting technique that you're already using
- otherwise give up. (There is no way to compare two strings for "<" in XSLT 1.0 other than creating a node-set and sorting it, and that requires the node-set extension).